# How to prepend block content in getSaveElement filter?

Tags: customization

I am using JSX format to make some edits to block content. My code is

```
// do something with these attributes - add header to section if exercise type block
const addContentTypeExtraProps = ( saveElementProps, blockType, attributes ) => {
    // Do nothing if it's another block than our defined ones.
    if ( ! enableBlockContentTypeAttribute.includes( blockType.name ) ) {
        return saveElementProps;
    }
    if ( attributes.contenttitle ) {
        // add header with anchor link and class name
        console.log(saveElementProps);
        var title_slug = attributes.contenttitle.trim().split(/\s+/).join('-');
        const Heading = "h" + 3;
        return (
            <Heading className=''>Test</Heading>+{saveElementProps}
        );
    }

};

addFilter( 'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps', 'my-mods/get-save-content/extra-props', addContentTypeExtraProps );
```

This results in

```
Block validation: Block validation failed for `uagb/section`
```

In block editor I see

```
Current
<section class="wp-block-uagb-section uagb-section__wrap uagb-section__background-undefined has-contenttype-exercise" id="uagb-section-db1983e4-fbaa-428b-84d7-15b6aa2a752c"><div class="uagb-section__overlay"></div><div class="uagb-section__inner-wrap"></div></section>
```

```
After Conversion
<section class="wp-block-uagb-section uagb-section__wrap uagb-section__background-undefined has-contenttype-exercise" id="uagb-section-db1983e4-fbaa-428b-84d7-15b6aa2a752c"><div class="uagb-section__overlay"></div><div class="uagb-section__inner-wrap"></div></section>
```

So my added HTML is not showing up, and the Current and After Conversion are showing identical.

I am new to React so probably not understanding how to use this `getSaveElement` filter...

Ideas?

Comment: Your callback should [return a *props* object](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsavecontent-extraprops) and not an element.

Comment: Ok, so blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps and blocks.getSaveElement are used in conjunction? One to set attributes, the other to modify content? Trying to figure out how these complement one another in terms of a final saved block that has some added content fields and attributes.

Comment: Yes, from the `blocks.getSaveElement`'s [definition](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsaveelement) - "*used to replace or extend the element, for example using `wp.element.cloneElement` to modify the element’s props or replace its children, or returning an entirely new element*".